# Looping Confusion

Tags: c++, for-loop, while-loop, switch-statement

My code seems to ask twice instead of once if I want to run the code again.  I just want it to run normally like my other cases which only ask once after I have viewed the activity and these two activities are the only ones with problems.  What seems to be the problem here:

```
case 5:
cout<<"Here are the list of activities in Activity 5:" << endl;
cout<<"[5.1]Determining a Number within the Array" << endl;
cout<<"[5.2]Determining the Highest and Lowest integer" << endl;
cout<<"[5.3]Reversed Array" << endl;
cin >> choice;
system("CLS");

        if(choice == 5.1){
            counter +=1;
            int nos[10];
            int det;
            cout <<"Note: Do not input any decimal numbers." << endl;
                for(int array = 1; array < 11; array++){

                    cout << "Input integers 1-10 only. [" << array << "]";
                    cin >> nos[det];
                                        }
                    cout << "Type in 1 integer value only.[" << det << "]";
                    cin >> det; 

                    if(det >= nos[1] || det <= nos[10]){
                        cout << "The value is within the scope of the array.";
                                        }
                    else{
                        cout << "The value is not within the scope of the array.";
                                        }
        system ("PAUSE");
        system ("CLS");
            cout << "Do you want to run the program again? (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> choose;
                        }

        else if(choice == 5.2){
            counter +=1;
        cout <<"Note: Do not input any decimal numbers." << endl;
        cout <<"Enter your integers." << endl;
        int nos[10];
        int put;
                for(int rep = 1; rep < 11; rep++){

                    cout <<"[" << rep << "]";
                    cin >> nos[rep];
                            }
                        int highnos = nos[1];
                        int lownos = nos[1];

                for(int rep = 1; rep < 11; rep++){
                if(nos[rep] > highnos){
                    highnos = nos[rep];
                                                    }           
                            }                           
                    cout << "Your highest integer is:" << highnos << endl;

                for(int rep = 1; rep > 11; rep++){
                if(nos[rep] < lownos){
                lownos = nos[rep];
                                    }
                                                }
        cout <<"Your lowest integer is:"<< lownos << endl;
            system ("PAUSE");
            system ("CLS");
            cout << "Do you want to run the program again? (y/n)" << endl;
            cin >> choose;

                                }
```

P.S. my activities also has errors but dont mind it :D

Comment: Copy this code into a new project and turn it into a function called by the new project's `main`. That will be much easier for you to experiment on while you hunt the bug AND put you closer to having the [mcve] you are required to have when making a post.

Comment: Array declared as `int nos[10]` has ten elements, indexed 0 through 9. `nos[10]` exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an index out of bounds. Further, you use `nos[det]` before `det` is initialized - another instance of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you haven't initialized anything so everything is taking garbage values.
initialize **det** first and if you want to input the whole array then run a loop. cin>>nos[det] only inputs one value at a garbage index according to your code.

This code is a mess. Kindly fix initializations and inputs, then share the output you're getting vs the output you want.